# Laravel Eloquent Relationships methods syntax

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

everyone:

I'm trying to create an application with several many to many relations, including a m-m rel onto the same model. It's a headache. In the official docs there is no so much information. I've been looking the code for belongsToMany method, in HasRelationShips.php, but there are not description on the parameters use.

Where can I get detailed documentation about the use of the parameters, in order to learn the right way to create any kind of relationships?

Do you know any book or document which details the working of all of the methods and parameters, so I can read it and REALLY learn how do they work?

Thanks everyone

Comment: See if [this](https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209) helps

Answer (score 0):

Bro, in the DOCs you can find it easily.

Belongs to Many is like that:

```
public function companys(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Users', 'companys_users', 'user_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();

    }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Yeah, as you can guess, I've read the official documentation bfore inserting my question. In the docs they show examples with up to 4 args, but the method signature has SEVEN args. It's like other relation methods, and that's why I'm looking for deeper, more detailed documentation. Thanks all the same.